# How to calculate sales of competing products in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to calculate two things in a database of product sales for different providers.

My database is in this format:

Provider - Product - Items sold
   A     -    P1   -     10
   A     -    P2   -     5
   B     -    P1   -     2
   B     -    P3   -     5
   C     -    P3   -     7
   C     -    P4   -     10

Where A, B and C are providers, P1, P2, P3 and P4 are different products, and the number on the right is the total sales for each provider and product for a certain period of time.

1) I'd like to calculate how many products of provider A are also sold by B (In the case of the example, that would be 1, because P1 is sold by A and B)
2) I'd like to calculate the percentage of total sales of provider A are of products which are also sold by B (in the example, 10 out of 15, because P1 is also sold by B [10 sold by A] over a total of 15 items sold by A)

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

I've tried different alternatives using Filter, Summarize and other functions, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate total sales for the current product by the current provider, divide it by total sales of current product by all providers:

```
Share % = 
VAR CurrentProduct = SELECTEDVALUE('Competitive Sales'[Product])
VAR CurrentProvider = SELECTEDVALUE('Competitive Sales'[Provider])
VAR TotalItemSold_CurrentProvider = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Competitive Sales'[Item Sold]),
        FILTER (
            ALL('Competitive Sales'),
            'Competitive Sales'[Product] = CurrentProduct &&
            'Competitive Sales'[Provider] = CurrentProvider
        )
    )

VAR TotalItemSold_AllProviders = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Competitive Sales'[Item Sold]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Competitive Sales'),
            'Competitive Sales'[Product] = CurrentProduct
        )
    )
RETURN DIVIDE(TotalItemSold_CurrentProvider, TotalItemSold_AllProviders)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pratik! Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand that with this approach, you would get the share each provider has for each product. Buy what I want to calculate is a single KPI to tell me how many of MY (provider A) products are competing with a certain competitor, say, B. In the example, I have only 1 product competing with B (P1), so of all my products, 50% are competing with B. That was question 1). And as another KPI, I would like to calculate the total items I sell of those competing products, as a proportion of all the items I sell: 10 / 15 as I sell 10 P1 of a total of 15 (P1+P2)

Comment: @JoseValenzuela Replace SUM('Competitive Sales'[Item Sold]) with COUNT('Competitive Sales'[Provider])